# Pyinstaller excuding package from executable file

Tags: python, module, package, pyinstaller

need to somehow create specfile or use some command during pyinstaller call so that pynput package should be **separated** from executable file that it produces, but not to break it.

This package is LGPL licensed and can't be included into `exe` file for some legal thing

```
a = Analysis(['app.py'],
             pathex=['.'],
             binaries=[('some_file.exe', '.')],
             datas=[...],
             hiddenimports=['pywinauto'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          name='some_name',
          exclude_binaries=True,
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='some_name')
```

Does anyone knows how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `--exclude-module` will exclude any module or package you don't want included in the exe.

If you're not using the command `--onefile` it shouldn't be included in the exe since all the scripts end up in their own folders separate from the exe

more information can be found in their documentation. On this topic specifically you'll find it under 'Options' in [what to bundle, where to search](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/man/pyi-makespec.html?highlight=--exclude-module#what-to-bundle-where-to-search)

Comment: it can't be excluded, because this package is not optional, as in `--exclude-module` definition. So I just need it to be separate from exe; sorry for misleading question :(

Comment: Also checked .exe file with pyi-archive_viewer and in PYZ-00.pyz `pynput` is still listed